# Reverse proxy in IIS to local TomCat

Tags: iis, tomcat, rewrite, url, arr

IIS has several websites:

- domain1.com
- a.domain2.com
- b.domain2.com

There is also a TomCat running on

```
localhost:8087
```

The challenge is how to expose the TomCat externally as

```
b.domain2.com
```

What I did:

- Enabled Proxy in ARR in IIS
- Added Reverse Proxy URL Rewrite rules on 
  b.domain2.com

  ```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8087/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      <outboundRules>
          <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" >
              <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:8087/(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://femiscan.a2itsolutionsllc.com/{R:2}" />
          </rule>

          <preConditions>
              <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                  <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
              </preCondition>
          </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
  ```

What I see:

**Locally**
if I navigate to

```
http://b.domain2.com
```

my browser shows TomCat website as

```
http://localhost:8087
```

(Why?)

**Externally** if I navigate in Chrome to

```
http://b.domain2.com
```

it tries to tunnel to

```
http://localhost:8087
```

If I navigate in IE it returns 500 error (Fiddler: HTTP/1.1 500 URL Rewrite Module Error.)

Question: What am I doing wrong? Can it be done and how?

Comment: This might be better addressed in the SuperUser SE.

Answer (score 4):

Your Action is set to Rewrite so it is rewriting the URL.

In IIS Manager:

- Right-click Server Farms, click "Create Server Farm". Give it some name.
- Put the fully-qualified domain name to your Tomcat instance in the "Server name or address" field
- Click "Advanced settings...", expand "applicationRequestRouting" and change httpPort to `8087`
- Click "Yes" when prompted to create a rewrite rule
- Click the newly created farm under "Server Farms" in the pane on the left side of the window
- Open "Routing Rules" on the Server Farm feature view page
- Click the "URL Rewrite..." link on the right pane
- Remove the old attempted Tomcat rewrite rule
- Click "Add Rule(s)..." at the top of the right pane, choose "Blank rule"
- Give it a name
- In the Match URL pane:

  - Requested URL: `Matches the Pattern`
  - Using: `Regular Expressions`
  - Pattern: `*`
- Expand the Conditions pane, click "Add"

  - Condition input: `{HTTP_HOST}`
  - Check if input string: `Matches the pattern`
  - Pattern: `b.domain2.com`
  - Check `Ignore Case`
- In the Action pane:

  - Action type: `Route to Server Farm`
  - Scheme: `http://`
  - Server farm: `(the name of your server farm)`
  - Path: `{R:1}` (**NOTE:** This may need some tinkering but judging by your example it should work)
- Click "Apply" on the right pane and your

Comment: The only thing that I did different was making the URL pattern `.*` instead of `*` in the Match URL pane, and everything worked perfectly.